# How to vertically align a textview field using table row in Android

Tags: android, row

I have this output

http://www.cubixshade.com/images/align_row.jpg

I want first field that is date field to be align vertically center?
and what should i use use to add some space from left or right in other field also?

Answer (score 14):

You can set `android:gravity="center_vertical"` property to TableRow to align its child vertically center.

Also you can use `android:layout_marginLeft` property or `android:layout_marginRiight` property to put some margins from left and right similarly you can put margin to top and bottom using `android:layout_marginTop` or `android:layout_marginBottom`.

If you want to stretched column then you can use the `android:layout_weight` property to define the weight of the column.

For reference you can see below example with 2 columns

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/TableLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="1" >

    <TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Male"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etNoOfMale"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:inputType="number"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Female"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etNoOfFemale"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:inputType="number"/>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

U can use tags likes below in your xml file page to align proper, If can give the details about the pblm you are facing I can give more explanation.

```
android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
```

the first code gives a margin of 25dp from the left and the second code just align the filed to right under the imageview1.

**And there is one another method**
Just right click on the text-view or anything you added in the design page the select the Other properties->layout parameters->then select the item you need[it contains all the align properties.

Hope this one help you. Thank you